# Possibility of connecting two PCs through a virtual switch

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualization, network-adapter

I want to connect two of my PCs through a third PC running [OVS](http://openvswitch.org).

Here's a diagram of how it would look:

[image: How it look like]

PC2 would be running OVS under Ubuntu and I would install two NICs (HP Intel Pro 1000 CT GbE Card) in it as well. Then I would connect PC1 and PC3 to the NICs installed in PC2.

Is this possible?  How can I do it?

Comment: Do you even need OVS for that? This is just a basic bridge.

Comment: Yes, i know that but I want to test some distributions of vSwitch (especially with DPDK).